# Rest Multiview active index after post back

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a webpage with a multiview and two view. When I click a submit button it goes to view number 2. When I refresh the page I want it to go back to View 1, but it is not working. The page refreshes with view 2 on screen.

Comment: In the code behind, you explicit set the ActiveView or the ActiveIndex (to 0) with !IsPostback is true

Answer (score 0):

set a cookie in view1 and in view2 check if cookie isnt null show content and after that clear cookie(set time for this cookie to past) otherwise(if cookie is null) redirect to view1, now when you refresh view2 becouse cookie is null it redirect to view1

some sodo codes(javascript):

view1:

```
set cookie;
```

view2:

```
if(cookie != "")
{
    //show page
    delete cookie;
}
else
{
   redirect to view1;
}
```